# python 3.3 and pip tool installation

Tags: configuration

Pip3 installation and Python 3.3 on windows vista

I have been using python 3.2 for a short time and I wanted to install `pygame` and other other packages. At that point I realised that I have to install pip tool as a package manager. In short, in the process, I removed python 3.2 and installed properly python 3.3 and encountered the following problems:

From python 3.3 interactive interpreter:

when I do: `pip --version` I get:

> nameerror pip not defined

When I go `Python get-pip.py` I get

> syntaxerror and the get is in red

`sudo python 3.3 setup.py install` gives error as well

But I was able to download the **`get-pip.py` script** and this script is inside my download manager. Again,there is no pip tool when I checked my python3.3 script directory.

Thank you in advance for your attention

Answer (score 0):

Usually get-pip.py runs.If nothing is working, try the wheel file. Download the .whl file and run:

```
python.exe pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx a lot and I shall get back to you within a short time

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it and accept my answer. Thanks